# How to resolve POM.XML error in Java SpringBoot Web Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have already version 3.6.3 of Maven.

This is the error code that I get while trying to setup the project:

> The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]  The project com.example:ikub:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\German\Desktop\ikub\pom.xml) has 1 error
> Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.16.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.16.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.16.RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

My `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/><!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ikub</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>ikub</name>
<description>Spring Boot iKub Project</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/><!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: The problem is probably in your maven configuration. Check the repository url and make sure it starts with `https` and not `http`.

Comment: I added the 's' at the end of 'http' but nothing changed @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Try to check your IDE maven settings or the JDK referenced to

Comment: this looks like either a miss-configuration at your POM / maven level or an issue with a proxy that's blocking maven's requests.